# Why does asp.net zero application service not have try and catch exception?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to asp.net zero framework. I just wanted to know if there are any reasons why the sample asp.net code do not use try catch blocks in the Application Service folder. For instance we have the sample code below that was already included - it appears that the try and catch are not included for a reason, but why?

[image]

Comment: What do you expect it to suggest in the catch block? A comment saying `// handle the exception here` ?

Comment: I was expecting something like to log an error in an errorlog database. But I assumed that "may be" there are other mechanisms already handling it in the framework. I am still new to this framework and need to dig deeper to understand how it works.

Comment: @avdeveloper ok, logging is fine, but why is that `IsTenantAvailable`'s job? that might be common in some higher level work pump/loop, but you don't need to sprinkle it into every method (we have the stack trace to see where the exception came from, so logging it on the way out of every method is overkill)

Comment: This method handles business exception excellently by the way. It just does not concern itself with handling run-time exceptions (someone unplugged the network cable and FindByTenancyNameAsync fails). It can't do anything to mitigate it, so it just doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

`try`/`catch` isn't something you add "just because" - you would add it because there's something useful you can do in some scenario where an exception is expected. Presumably, then, there is no scenario where that applies here; it is not *expected* that an exception should happen, so if one does occur: something is wrong, and just let it raise. You shouldn't make a habit of hiding exceptions without a good reason (such as: you've handled an anticipated failure and recovered successfully).

In many ways, `try`/`finally` should be more common in most code than `try`/`catch`, and even then that should mostly be compiler-generated via `using`.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm missing something, but isn't `using` only giving you the `try / finally` guarantee of calling `Dispose()`?   I don't think `using` will do any good if an object doesn't implement `IDisposable` or you need to do other cleanup.  Granted, I'm aware that's a good argument for implementing that interface to begin with.

Comment: @Zer0 yes, that only applies to `IDisposable` (and now `IAsyncDisposable`, and the `ref struct` duck-typed dispose) - and that kind of resource cleanup is probably the most common `try`/`finally` scenario that exists (if we ignore `foreach` and pretend that it too uses `try`/`finally` as an intermediate step in the optional iterator disposal)